# Two days per year, Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

> A person works at 1 to 3 of 5 different places and eats 1 to 3 of 4 different meals every day. Prove there were two days in a year where he ate the exact same meals and worked at the exact same place.

**MY ANSWER**

The ensemble of combinations can be described as the sum of the sets of workplaces: $\sum_{i=1}^{3}\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,i\right)$ times the sum of sets of meals: $\sum_{n=1}^{3}\operatorname{nCr}\left(4,n\right)$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{3}\operatorname{nCr}\left(4,n\right)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{3}\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,i\right)=350$$
Since $350<365$ then the 15 last days must be repetitions of a combination that happened in the initial 350 days.

Is this a proper reading of the situation?

Comment: "*then the last 15 days must be repetitions*"  this is incorrect.  All that pigeonhole principle says is that there must be at least one repetition *somewhere* in the list... but not *where* such a repetition occurs.  It could be the first 350 days are all the same and the last fifteen are all unique for all we know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math is fine, but $\mathrm{nCr}(4,n)$ is bizarre. In ${}_nC_r$ notation for binomial coefficients, you would just write ${}_4C_n$. But it's more common to write $C^4_n$, and it's even more common than that to write $\binom4n$. So I would write
$$
   \left(\binom51 + \binom52 + \binom 53\right) \cdot \left(\binom 41 + \binom42 + \binom43\right)
$$
which simplifies to $(5 + 10 + 10) \cdot (4 + 6 + 4) = 25 \cdot 14 = 350$. The summation notation $$\sum_{i=1}^3 \binom5i \cdot \sum_{j=1}^3 \binom 4j$$ is also fine.

Additionally, getting $350 < 365$ tells us that there must be at least $15$ days that are repeats of previous days (which is all you need to know here), but it does *not* tell us that the last $15$ days are the repeats. For example, maybe the person worked at the same place and ate the same thing for the first $100$ days of the year, and then decided to keep trying new options for the next $265$ days.

Comment: That was just me copying straight from Desmos. Thanks for elaborating!